# Python: formatting errors

Tags: python

I refactored `add()` so that I could easily output errors by writing a regex pattern to find anything that contains negatives or ends in a newline. However, I went into the console to make sure the errors were being printed properly and realized that it doesn't print out the newline character. Is there any way to actually print out the newline character instead of the console printing out an extra space?

What I would like to see:
`ValueError: -1, -2, \n`

What I'm currently getting:
`ValueError: -1, -2`

**Production:**

```
def add(expr):
    """Returns an evaluated sum or raises an error."""
    errors = re.findall(r"(-\d+|\n$)", expr)
    if any(errors):
        raise ValueError("Errors: {}".format(", ".join(errors)))                                                                                                         
    return __result(expr)


def __result(expr):
"""Returns the evaluated sum of the expression."""
delim = __delimiter(expr)
return sum([int(i) for i in expr.replace("\n", delim).split(delim) if
            i.strip().isdigit()])
```

**Test:**

```
class TestStringCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add_invalid_string(self):                                              
        """Should raise error if invalid string."""                                 
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):                                         
            add("1,\n")

    def test_add_negative_digits(self):
        """Should raise error if negatives found."""                                
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            add("-1,2")
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - why is `add`ing a negative number an error?

Comment: Anyway.. although I don't quite get what you're trying to do, is: `raise ValueError("Errors: {}\n".format(", ".join(errors)))` what you're after - although not sure why you'd want a newline in the exception message itself...

Comment: @JonClements I want the newline to be printed in the exception message. Also, it's part of a dojo exercise by Roy Osherove so I'm following his specs. http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/

Comment: Then just put the `\n` in the raise as I've suggested I guess

Comment: @JonClements I don't want to actually add a newline, I want that character to be printed in the actual message. For example: ```ValueError: -1, -2, \n```

Comment: Then you have to catch the exception, then print it as desired... I'm feeling I'm missing something obvious though...

Comment: The pattern I wrote just returns an array of negative values (if found) or a newline character (only if the expression ends with "\n".) All I would like is to print out that newline which ```format()``` should've printed for me, but for whatever reason it's ignoring it.  @JonClements

Comment: It's not ignoring it, it's turning it into a *new line*. If you what the character sequence ``r'\n'`` to appear, you need to escape the ``\`` in the original string. But note you're no longer actually putting a newline in the string, you're placing a representation of it in.

Comment: Okay - it works for me... not quite sure what else you're expecting your code to do... think @aruisdante has the question that needs to be answered...